# How to fix Exception: forward transform failed with error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits 

Tags: qgis, export

Export to vector file failed.

```
Error: Failed to transform a point while drawing a feature of type 'Dingalan_Brgy_Boundary'. Writing stopped. (Exception: forward transform of
(5731.78, 29676.2)

failed with error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits
)
```

Comment: the error means the re-projection to the new coordinate system is failing. What is your source CRS and what CRS are you trying to export?

Answer (score 6):

The layer's CRS settings are wrong. 5731.78, 29676.2 cannot be valid latitude/longitude values. That's why the transformation fails.

To fix this: Go to layer properties and correct the CRS setting there.

Answer (score 0):

If data was downloaded from GeoServer to QGIS using the database directly try to project to exact CRS so that this error can be skipped.