# QGis points distance from shore in metres

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-2, raster-conversion, proximity, rasterization

I have a grid of depth points in the Irish Sea that i'm trying to add other data fields to, in this case distance from shore. I've tried both of [these](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28038/calculating-the-minimum-distance-between-points-and-polygons-in-qgis) suggestions to no avail, but am having some success with [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis) one. My problem is that the resulting raster [image: resulting raster] has distances as decimal degrees rather than metres.

I've changed my project properties > canvas units to metres, re-done the rasterise, re-done the proximity, but it's still decimal degrees. Any ideas how I can get the results in metres?

Comment: are the canvas and vector layer set to a projected CRS? the proximity process might select it's units based on the coordinate system being used, rather than what is displayed

Comment: Both are WGS84, but it seems I can change the project properties to metres but often it seems to have changed back to degrees...

Comment: you could try running it with data projected to UTM or another appropriate projected grid and see if it works better that way. I have had a number of tools have a similar issue in ArcGIS in the past

Comment: hmm... trying with project as WGS84 pseudo-mercator as project CRS and vector layer's CRS, but resulting raster comes out as WGS84 (which I can obviously change) and 1 unit per pixel comes out as 1 degree rather than 1 metre. Do you think that should have potentially worked, or is WGS84-P.M. technically distinct from UTM? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know the details of PM, but if it didn't work, test out a different one UTM (Zone 30 I think), or the british national grid, If that doesn't work, hopefully one of the qgis guru's on here can make a suggestion

Comment: alas, BNG yields the same results. Thanks for trying, in any case! So have you got this working in QGis or only Arc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underdark's answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23856/what-is-up-with-qgis-buffer-tool-units/23863#23863) did the job: save the coastline polygon as British National Grid (Mercator gave [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/why-do-i-get-failed-to-transform-when-reprojecting-from-wgs84-to-google-mercat) error), then convert that to raster (again, select BNG as the CRS), then do the proximity tool. Cheers @TDavis for getting me started on the right path!